# Ubuntu stops using Nvidia driver after kernel upgrade

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, display, monitor

Just updated and restarted, Ubuntu's doesn't display correctly. After restart, the desktop now looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgsHr.png). I've temporarily switched to the Nouveau driver.

The update history reveals the kernel was updated, amongst many things; and the following were installed:

```
linux-image-3.5.0-19-generic (3.5.0-19.30)
linux-image-extra-3.5.0-19-generic (3.5.0-19.30)
```

I've encountered this type of problem [quite recently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214150/ubuntu-12-10-wont-display-properly-after-kernel-upgrade), so I decided to reapply the same steps, to solve the problem, as follows:

```
sudo  apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-19
sudo  apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic
sudo  depmod -a
sudo  modprobe nvidia
sudo  /etc/init.d/*dm restart
```

When installing `linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic`, I get an error, message from terminal as follows:

```
Setting up linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic (3.5.0-19.30) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.5.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic
Error! Problems with depmod detected.  Automatically uninstalling this module.
DKMS: Install Failed (depmod problems).  Module rolled back to built state.
```

However, I ignored the above error and continued the steps with `sudo  depmod -a`, re-installed `nvidia-current`(because it was removed when activating Nouveau driver), then did `sudo  modprobe nvidia`, which yielded the following error:

```
FATAL: Error inserting nvidia_current (/lib/modules/3.5.0-19-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_current.ko): No such device
```

**Update:** Upon restart, the Nvidia driver now works! BTW, do those error messages imply I broke something; am I on the right track? Just curious, cause I don't want to get happy I've fixed it, then it stops working later on.

Finally, how can I prevent this from happening in future?

The system is Dell XPS-L702X, with NVIDIA GeForce GT 555M, and 17" screen.

Comment: have any ppa's or did you install this manually?  Because I never have this error when installing using Nvidia Current from the repos.

Comment: @Goddard I didn't encounter any of those problems when installing `nvidia-current`. Rather, the 2 errors were encountered when installing `linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic`, and then another one when running `sudo modprobe nvidia`. However, the Nvidia driver now works, but I'm left curious if those messages imply something was broken.

Answer (score 1):

when there is a new kernel-update by update-manager, then simply
after reboot - with ubuntu-package manager uninstall nvidia-drivers (and bumblebee) - then
install nvidia-drivers again.

this looks inconvenient, but its easier ?!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this error can be ignored and after a restart the nvidia driver will be correctly loaded.