# Did my updates in 12.10 break my display driver (nvidia)

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I was so stoked, it's been my best linux experience to date. Everything was running grandly, til I let the updates do there thing, post reboot only one display worked which was labeled as laptop and the second display would not respond.

I found instructions to remove and re-install, doesn't work (though it's back to two monitors they display at 640x480 which I can't change) (That post is located here [Ubuntu 12.10 won't display properly after kernel upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214150/ubuntu-12-10-wont-display-properly-after-kernel-upgrade))

sudo  modprobe nvidia

tells me 'Fatal module not present'

I'd rather not start from scratch again this weekend, so suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `linux-headers-generic` and `linux-source` packages so the nvidia proprietary drivers can install properly.

1. Get into login screen after booting.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
3. Login with your username/password and run the following commands:

   sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*

   sudo apt-get install linux-source

   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

   sudo apt-get install nvidia-(whatever version you want to install)
   nvidia-xconfig

   sudo shutdown -r now

You may have a weird post-grub screen (plymouth) but that is another bug. It should let you now login and setup your dual display properly.

You can also try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal right after logging and so typing

software-center -> Will open ubuntu software center so you can install sources and headers-generic
software-properties-gtk -> Then navigate to other drivers and get back to Nouveau drivers or install whatever nvidia proprietary driver you want.

Comment: Hi. thanks for that seems to have worked,

One thing that was interesting is the last step nvidia-xconfig just throws an error, yet rebooting post the rest seemed to work out okay, maybe I mis-understood and (nvidia-xconfig) was meant to be part of the install command?

Comment: No, its not part I just messed with the lines.

Just after the "... install nvidia-****", when it finishes, make nvidia-xconfig (should tell you about a file created /etc/X11/.. Anyways, its not a must-do as the driver would automatically do when hes selected to work from.